# CLIPS conditional rule

Tags: if-statement, clips

How can I make conditional rule in CLIPS to find the output

For example

```
(deftemplate holiday
(slot hotel (allowed-symbols nice good poor))
(slot weather (allowed-symbols sunny raining))
)
(deftemplate output
(slot option (allowed-symbols go plan stay))
)
```

Whith this this, how do we create a rule like

```
if hotel = poor then stay
if hotel = poor and weather = raining then stay
if (hotel = poor and weather = sunny) or (hotel = good and weather = raining) then plan
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (defrule hotel-rule1
       (holiday (hotel ?hotel&:(eq ?hotel poor)))
       =>
       (assert (output (option stay)))
    )

(defrule hotel-rule2
       (holiday (hotel ?hotel&:(eq ?hotel poor)) (weather ?weather&:(eq ?weather raining)))
       =>
       (assert (output (option stay)))
    )
```

I would split the "or" condition of your last rule in two different rules, similar to the examples I wrote.

Bye
Nic

Comment: Thank Nic. I get an error: [EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for option. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it is working. I didn't copy your code correctly. Thanks

Comment: You can directly match the constants rather than binding the variable and making a call to the eq function. For example, instead of (holiday (hotel ?hotel&:(eq ?hotel poor)) (weather ?weather&:(eq ?weather raining))), use (holiday (hotel poor) (weather raining))